# Why are TimeSeries objects reported with head "TemporalData"?

Tags: version-10, time-series

**Related Problem: What does it mean to be an object in Mathematica?**

I am quite surprised to find that

```
ts = TimeSeries[ {1,2,3,4}, {{1,2,3,4}}];
Head @ ts
```

returns

```
(* TemporalData *)
```

I do find this quite inconsistent as the object is also reported with TimeSeries[...] when it is generated. I would find it much more sensible to have TemporalData-functions also accept TimeSeries objects but still have them as special instances with a "Head" of their own.

More formally: If `TimeSeries`is a constructor then it should generate a `TemporalData`object and I should not see TimeSeries[...] at all after applying the function. On the other hand if it is a data type of its own then it should have its own head.

Am I missing something here? (e.g. are there good reasons for this behavior or can it be avoided)

Comment: While every TimeSeries is a special case of TemporalData, the reverse is not true and thus by assigning the head "TemporalData" I am losing information which I now have to test for again (e.g. does the object only have one path?).

Comment: This is also true of `EventSeries`. Out of curiosity what information are you losing? You can always check for a single path with the "PathCount" property. There is also an undocumented "ObjectType" property which will tell you if it is a `TimeSeries` or generic `TemnporalData` object.

Comment: @Andy Ross You are right about EventSeries, my fault. To me it seems much better to have every function that accepts TemporalData also accept a TimeSeries object. That is easy to implement and still gives me the Head as an identifier (so I do not need to dig into undocumented properties). The object is also generated as TimeSeries[...] why bother then at all with giving this object name?

Comment: Since TimeSeries does "construct" a TemporalData object there is of course not difficulty here. But if - as I have written - TimeSeries is merely a constructor function then it should not report the generation of a TimeSeries object (as it certainly does). I am no computer scientist but I cannot help to find this simply inconsistent.

Comment: I absolutely agree.

Comment: I am also no CS and have always found TimeSeries awkward, even though I haven't given much thought to why. But, as to your concrete problem, how can we help? Changing the formatting of a TemporalData that comes from a TimeSeries? Creating a `TimeSeriesQ`?

Comment: I have always admired the scalability coming from the generality in Mma's deisng. I would propose two solutions: **Either** TimeSeries is *better documented* as a pure constructor function and there is no such result as `TimeSeries[__]` (yes, then something like `TimeSeriesQ` would make sense) **or** it is supported as an *object of its own* so that `Head@ts` returns `TimeSeries` and is made internally compatible with TemporalData-related functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First Analysis

The official (first answer) from the technical support at Wolfram Research states that:

> *This seems consistent with the overall design of Mathematica where the head of an object that is a special case of some larger class generally has the head of the larger class (e.g. plots generally have the head Graphics).*
>
> [...] *this may have some implications for bijectivity/invertibility* [but should not be a problem] *since most things in this area should have the head TemporalData.*

While I agree that the problem seems limited it imho still is a design question which may be interesting in general since more and more we are talking about **objects** in Mathematica where there used to be *atoms* and *normal expressions* only.

**I do not quite follow the logic with regard to the `Plot` example:**

```
g = Plot[x^2, {x,-2,2}];
Head @ g

(* Graphics *)
```

will give the more general head indeed but here we are talking about a **constructor**. (Please correct me since my knowledge about computer science stems from reading Roman Maeder's *Computer Science with Mathematica* ). And naturally we are interested in the information of the object (data type) that has been constructed.

Quite in accordance here we never again see reference to the constructor again:

```
(OwnValues @ g)[[1,2]]
(* shows a Graphics object *)
```

Also using `FullForm @ g` will show that there is not a trace left indicating the Graphics-Object to be a special case 'Plot' (rather than say a BarChart).

**This is different for `TimeSeries`:**

While at first the analogy holds

```
ts = TimeSeries[ {1,2,3,4}, {{ 1,2,3,4 }} ];
Head @ ts

(* TemporalData *)
```

It is different further down the road:

```
(OwnValues @ ts)[[1,2]]
(* shows TimeSeries[ ... ] *)
```

and referencing `FullForm @ ts` clearly shows that we are talking about a `TemporalData` object of subclass (?) `TimeSeries`, since

```
(FullForm @ ts)[[1,1]]
(* TimeSeries *)
```

*Note: As has been indicated by Andy Ross, the undocumented `ts["ObjectType"]` will serve as a `TimeSeriesQ` function.*

But here again I do get the impression that *deeper design change*s are at work:

```
expr = h[ e1, e2, e3, e4 ]; expr[[1]]

(* e1 *)
```

Compare this *Mathematica 1.0.1 -like* behavior to:

```
f = FullForm @ ts

(* TemporalData[TimeSeries, List[ ... ], False, 10.'] *)
```

which surprises when asked about its *first part*:

```
f[[1]]

(* returns more than simple *TimeSeries* , e.g. full information about 
number of data and times *)
```

**So it seems that object is not equal to object?**

### Proposal for further releases

I am not computer scientist enough to follow through the design implications at hand here but while I understood the Mathematica-design described by *Roman Maeder* I am struggling with some design changes in the latest releases of Mathematica.

***Possible Route 1***

Everything is kept as is but the documentation is at least made a bit more enlightening and maybe a `TimeSeriesQ` and `EventSeriesQ` is implemented for special instances.

***Possible Route 2***

`TimeSeries` is seen as a mere **constructor** and thus a (special case) of 'TemporalData[...]' is reported as the result (analog to Plot and the like for Graphics). Thus `OwnValues` would not show `TimeSeries` but `TemporalData`.

***Possible Route 3 (is there one?)***

Thinking and reading up about classes and subclasses I believe that subclasses **extend** classes they are special cases of but are referenced as a class in their own right. Maybe (using upvalues in Mma) one wants to tie separate methods to a TimeSeries - object while at the same time allowing for use of TimeSeries objects whenever a TemporalData object is asked for (e.g. `f[td_TemporalData]` might also accept a TimeSeries).

So this would mean leaving `TimeSeries[...]` as a FullForm Representation while changing the interpretation of `Head` (?) with regard to objects?

**Conclusion**

Not being savvy enough in this regard (but nontheless interested) I would see the first proposal as a minimal solution (for clarity) while prefering the 2nd route.

Comment: Seems that nobody has come up with another answer or cares, thus I accept my own thoughts reflecting upon the answer I have gotten from WRI.

Comment: I've come across the same issue with `QuantityArray`, which formats as though it still has head `QuantityArray` but really it's a `StructuredArray`.  It's a really unfortunate design decision in my opinion.  But just like the quantity case, there is a Q function for testing - ```TemporalData`TimeSeriesQ``` and ```QuantityArray`QuantityArrayQ```